# Android: Fragment's fields get cleared while entering Multi-Window mode

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment that is used in a `ViewPager`. Fragment instances are constructed via factory method like this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, List<String> aList) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.list = aList;
    return fragment;
}
```

The list is passed from the activity's `onCreate()` method to a `SectionsPagerAdapter` instance where I call `newInstance()` for my fragment. The list can never be null (there are checks in the code).

**Problem:** The application fails with NPE in `onStart()` method when I try to enter 
[Multi-Window view](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window). The list is null.

What I noticed is that the fields that I set in `newInstance()` call are now nulls. Only those that are initialized in `onCreateView()` are assigned with objects. I guess the system initializes my Fragment in a different way bypassing my `newInstance()` method.

**Question:** Why fields that are set in my factory method are set to null? Why it happens only in Multi-Window mode? How to prevent this?

Probably I misuse something, thought creating a fragment via factory method is what Astroid Studio offers by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never be setting data in your fragment like that because of this exact issue.

When your app goes into multi window mode your fragment/activity get recreated so any data you passed in like that is lost.

What you should be doing that does handles configuration changes is pass your data in a `bundle` to your fragment via `setArguments`. When your fragment loads you then get the `bundle` via `getArguments` then grab the information from the bundle and proceede as normal.

get/setArguments holds the bundle information through configuration changes

it would look something like this

```
myFragment =  new MyFragment();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putLong("list",aList);
myFragment.setArguments(b);
```

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that there might be a case when my fragment is instantiated in a different way (bypassing `newInstance()` call)? If it was constructed via activity's `onCreate` method the fields would never be null.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, A fragment is only created one way. Creating the fragment object is not creating the fragment. the fragment is created when you add it to the fragment manager

Answer (score 1):

Multi-window is a form of Configuration change. I bet if you rotate the device the same issue will occur.

In your Activity's AndroidManifest block, try adding the following (as a property of `<activity>`:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
```

This will tell Android that you want to handle Configuration changes yourself, and will call your Activity's (and Fragment's) `onConfigurationChanged()` method instead of handling itself. Leave that method alone and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate a bit more on why this happens? Why doesn't it  instantiate my Fragment the way it supposed to instantiate? I also haven't found any documentation that could prove that the system might wipe out some fields or instantiate my classes in different way.

Solving the problem is quite strait forward - so far I simply turned off the multi-window mode via `android:resizeableActivity="false"`.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota Basically, you're doing it wrong. See tyczj's answer. You can pass an `ArrayList<String>` in a Bundle so you should be fine to use the proper method.